# Does linux software raid10 perform any data verification on each write?

Tags: mdadm, raid10

I wand to find out is there any benefit in safety of storage data between manual sync(using cron & rsync) of two RAID0 volumes and RAID10 volume using Linux software raid. Does RAID10 preform any data integrity check during write operation? Something like write on volume1, write on volume2 compare check sums

Comment: — compare checksums of what? THINK!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You are comparing Apples to Great White Sharks: The `rsync` process is a backup.  RAID is ***not a backup***.

If you want a local backup use the scheduled rsync.  If you want real-time mirroring across two striped volumes use RAID 10.

---

From a data integrity standpoint the only benefit to cron'd `rsync` between two RAID 0 volumes is that the data on the shadow volume will be "behind" the live one: If you delete an important file from the live volume you can read it back from the shadow volume, provided the rsync hasn't happened yet.
RAID does not offer this shadow delay time: You delete the file and it's gone.

RAID 10 provides standard disk-write integrity checks: Each container will have the same data - the OS and the disk controller guarantee that (when you write to the RAID 10 the disk controller writes the same data to each stripe).  Additionally RAID 10 allows the OS to read from either stripe, which offers the potential of better read performance if you are using decent disks and controllers.